# Por que minha função ao ser executada só retorna "0"?

Tags: c, string, algoritmo

Estou fazendo uma função que recebe uma string (`char str[10]`) e ela tem que retornar 1 se a *string* conter a palavra “asa” e, caso contrário, retornar 0.

Para ficar mais fácil de entender o que tentei fazer, vou mostrar um exemplo:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

x s a s a t i \0
```

Nesse caso, a função tem que retornar 1 porque a palavra “asa” está contida na *string* recebida (posições 2, 3 e 4).

O código que eu fiz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int vetorPalavra(char str[10]){
    int i, cont;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        if((str[i] == 'a') && (str[i] == 's')){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
main(){
    fflush(stdin);
    char str[10] = {'x','d','m','a','s','a','h','k','p','g'};
    printf("%i", vetorPalavra(str));
}
```

Na função `main()`, observem que eu já coloquei os valores do vetor. Então não é necessário inserir nada ao executar. Ele já exibirá o valor direto (0 ou 1). Entretanto, ao executar ele só mostra o valor 0, quando era pra mostrar 1. O que fiz de errado?

[image: Resultado]

Ja tentei usar `fflush(stdin)`, mas não adiantou de nada. Pensei em usar contador mas acho que nesse exercício não iria funcionar.

Comment: `if((str[i] == 'a') && (str[i] == 's'))` o caractere `str[i]` pode ser `a` ou `s` não os dois simultaneamente  não seria ``if((str[i] == 'a') || (str[i] == 's'))`` ?

Comment: Podia clicar no "✓" da resposta do Manero, né? Ele deu a resposta correta.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Faltou comparar com a letra `a` e andar no índice em cada letra. Se achou o `a` em um elemento do *array*, para ser válido **o próximo** elemento deve ser `s`, e **o seguinte** deve ser `a`. O código da pergunta está comparando com o mesmo elemento, o que é impossí9vel ele ser duas coisas diferentes ao mesmo tempo, mas nem é essa intenção, tem que comparar com três elementos em sequência de cada vez.

Outro problema é que se ele não achar na primeiro oportunidade encerra a busca dizendo que não tem, e isto só deve acontecer quando ele buscar em toda a *string*, caso contrário nem precisaria de um laço.

É tudo questão de interpretar o problema corretamente e traduzir isso em código.

Este algoritmo só funciona com *strings* formadas corretamente e com o tamanho esperado (pode ter uma pequena variação), conforme o que fala no enunciado. O código não cria uma *string* formada corretamente. Para fazer funcionar com um *array* de caracteres que não é uma *string* a busca deve terminar 2 caracteres antes para não pegar lixo de memória para comparar. Como otimização o código novo já faz isto.

Organizando e corrigindo outros problemas menores:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int vetorPalavra(char str[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) if (str[i] == 'a' && str[i + 1] == 's' && str[i + 2] == 'a' ) return 1;
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    printf("%d", vetorPalavra("xdmasahkp"));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GLw0hB). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/gkymivbc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/FindString.c).

Só a título de curiosidade se realmente a comparação deveria ser só com o começo da *string* e não em toda ela, a função poderia ter só esta linha:

```
return str[0] == 'a' && str[1] == 's' && str[2] == 'a';
```

Comment: Por que não da erro erro se não tiver `asa` na palavra e o último caractere ser `a`? Achei que ia dar out of range no i+1 e i+2

Comment: Não existe `out of range` em C. Leia o 4o. parágrafo.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
int vetorPalavra(char str[10]){
 int i;
 for(int i = 0;i<9;i++){
  if((str[i] == 'a') && (str[i + 1] == 's') && (str[i + 2] == 'a')){
   return 1;
  }
  else{
   return 0;
  }
 }
}
main(){
 printf("%i", vetorPalavra("xdmasahkp"));
}
Tentei fazer como disse, mas deu a mesma coisa

Comment: Não dá: https://ideone.com/GLw0hB

Comment: Não, é assim que se faz. O seu não está igual ao meu, se você copiar e colar funcionará. Se ler a resposta aprenderá como fazer e porque o seu não dá certo.